# Sankey Diagram in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'd like to run the example of a sankey diagram from bl.ocks.org (http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13), but when I run it with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

from the folder with index.html, sankey.js and sankey-formatted.json in the following line

```
source.sourceLinks.push(link);
```

Gives an error:

```
sankey.js:91TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'source.sourceLinks.push')
```

The function this code is from is:

```
  links.forEach(function(link) {
  var source = link.source,
      target = link.target;
  if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
  if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
  source.sourceLinks.push(link);
  target.targetLinks.push(link);
});
```

and my json file is:

```
{
"nodes": [
{
  "name": "Africa"
}, 
{
  "name": "America"
}, 
...
],
"links":[
{
  "source": "Africa", 
  "target": "America", 
  "value": 1
}, 
{
  "source": "America", 
  "target": "Africa", 
  "value": 2
}, 
...
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Populate the sourceLinks and targetLinks for each node.
  // Also, if the source and target are not objects, assume they are indices.
  function computeNodeLinks() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks = [];
      node.targetLinks = [];
    });
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      var source = link.source,
          target = link.target;
      if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
      if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
      source.sourceLinks.push(link);
      target.targetLinks.push(link);
    });
  }
```

I think you are missing something in your data structure. Try it again with this remodeled data. Namely the `node` index, this is needed for the links to be set up.

```
{
"nodes": [
  {
    "node" : 0,
    "name": "Africa"
  }, 
  {
    "node" :1,
    "name": "America"
  }, 
  {
    "node" :2,
    "name": "Europe"
  }
],
"links":[
  {
    "source": 0, 
    "target": 2, 
    "value": 1
  }, 
  {
    "source": 1, 
    "target": 2, 
    "value": 2
  }, 
  {
    "source": 0, 
    "target": 1, 
    "value": 1
  }
]}
```

[Plunker Example](https://embed.plnkr.co/tOK8SjVpfHiT75Vtughn/)